# How can I add another tab that looks exactly like the first one (like in a browser)?

Tags: qt

I have a browser made in Qt and a I have a tabwidget with one tab (which has a label, lineedit and a webview). I want to add others that look like the first one (have label, lineedit and webview).

How can I do this?

Comment: That's a tough question without knowing anything about how you implemented the first tab. The usual way of doing the others is doing exactly the same thing as for the first.

Comment: well the first one i designed it didn t write code for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any way to "clone" or duplicate an existing tab or widget, so I believe you'll need to code the tab contents yourself (i.e. not through the designer).

If all you need are a QLabel, a QLineEdit and a QWebView, that's not very complex. The idea would be to:

- create a custom widget (inheriting from `QWidget` directly, or from `QFrame`)
- lay out the contained widgets in the fashion you want in its constructor
- add as many tabs as you want, when you want them, via the `QTabWidget.addTab` function.

The [Tab Dialog](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/dialogs-tabdialog.html) example has everything you need - it's actually more complex than what you need because it uses different widgets for each tab. You can get away with a single widget.

If you wonder how to do the layout, and you're satisfied with what you got from the designer, you can inspect the generated (`.moc`) files. You'll see what layouts it uses, and you can replicate that in your own code.

Skeleton widget:

```
class BrowserTab : public QWidet
{
     Q_OBJECT

 public:
     BrowserTab(QUrl const& home, QWidget *parent = 0);
     void setUrl(QUrl const& url);

 private:
     QWebView *web;
     QLabel *title;
     QLineEdit *urlEdit;
};


BrowserTab::BrowserTab(QUrl const& home, QWidget *parent)
  : QWidget(parent)
{
   urlEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
   title = new QLabel(this);
   web = new QWebView(this);

   QVBoxLayout *vl = new QVBoxLayout;
   vl->addLayout(title);
   vl->addLayout(urlEdit);
   vl->addLayout(web);
   setLayout(vl);

   setUrl(home);
}

void BrowserTab::setUrl(QUrl const& url)
{
    web->load(url);
    // update label & urlEdit here
}
```

You'll need to do a bit more to make it a proper browser (`setUrl` should probably be a slot too), but this should get you started.